Create Function issue in the Vertica
I want to create this function but facing issue
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RAW.getType(input_string VARCHAR)
RETURN VARCHAR AS
BEGIN
   RETURN (
        SELECT Type
        FROM RAW.TYPE
        WHERE LENGTH(input_string) = LENGTH  
          AND input_string LIKE PATTERN || '%' 
         LIMIT 1 
     );
 END;

Gives Error as Column "input_string" does not exist
also tried with declare result
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RAW.getType(num VARCHAR)
RETURN VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR;

    SELECT Type INTO result
    FROM RAW.TYPE
    WHERE LENGTH(num) = LENGTH  
      AND num LIKE PATTERN || '%'  
    LIMIT 1;  

    RETURN result;
END;

This gives the syntax error
Need to create function query for above select query

There are no functions involving a SELECT in Vertica. You could solve that by creating a stored procedure inserting the result into a table, or by coding a function with one or more out parameters involving a SELECT. Can you supply a minimal example of your raw.type table with a few rows - I could code an exemplary stored procedure to illustrate.

Yes @marcothesane,  select * from raw.type;
LENGTH | PATTERN |       TYPE
--------+---------+-------------------
8  | 43       | HOME Mobile
10 | 9143   | HOME Mobile
10 | 9125   | HOME LandLine
8  | 25       | HOME LandLine  So if I pass RAW.getType(9143567830) I should get HOME Mobile

You need to pack SELECT-s into a PROCEDURE, not a FUNCTION in Vertica.
You could work with inout parameters, though - I can't say if they fit your purpose, as you can't, for example, embed them into a SELECT that is not at the top level of your query. This works however:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS raw.type (srch,type) AS (
            SELECT 'aaaaaaa',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 'bbbbbbb',2
  UNION ALL SELECT 'ccccccc',3
  UNION ALL SELECT 'ddddddd',4
  UNION ALL SELECT 'eeeeeee',5
);
-- out CREATE TABLE
-- out Time: First fetch (0 rows): 10.143 ms. All rows formatted: 10.203 ms

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE raw.getType(
 INOUT input_string VARCHAR
,OUT _type INT
) LANGUAGE PLvSQL SECURITY INVOKER AS $$
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'searching with  %', input_string;
     SELECT srch,type
     INTO input_string,_type
     FROM raw.type
     WHERE srch LIKE input_string || '%' ;
END;
$$;
-- out CREATE PROCEDURE
-- out Time: First fetch (0 rows): 16.096 ms. All rows formatted: 16.197 ms

CALL raw.getType('d');
-- out NOTICE 2005:  searching with  d
-- out  input_string | _type 
-- out --------------+-------
-- out  ddddddd      |     4
-- out (1 row)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (1 row): 81.213 ms. All rows formatted: 81.338 ms                  


But I want use it in my final select query but I can't call procedure from select query right?
